# Write text and bookmarks to a Word template embedded in a workbook

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

(This question is a follow-up on [how to work with a document embedded in an Excel workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54419143/3077495) in the Word application interface (instead of in-place). The reason this is necessary is to be able to save the result as an independent document.)

This code is doing what is needed to do. Opening embedded Word template, filling it in and saving it as new copy. The only part that is not working is `.Application.Quit False`. Getting Word error: "Microsoft Word has stopped working". What can be the possible reason of this failure?

```
Sub opentemplateWord()
Dim sh As Shape
Dim objOLE As OLEObject
Dim objWord As Object 'Word.Document
Dim objRng As Object 'Word.Range
Dim objUndo As Object 'Word.UndoRecord
Dim cell As Excel.Range
Dim xlRng As Excel.Range
Dim xlSht As Worksheet


Set xlSht = Sheets("Main")

With xlSht
  Set xlRng = .Range("E1", .Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With

''The shape holding the object from 'Create from file'
''Object 2 is the name of the shape
Set sh = Worksheets("Templates").Shapes("WordFile")
''Activate the contents of the object
sh.OLEFormat.Activate
Set objOLE = sh.OLEFormat.Object
Set objWord = objOLE.Object

With objWord
  Set objRng = .Range.Characters.Last
  Set objUndo = .Application.UndoRecord
  objUndo.StartCustomRecord ("Doc Data")
  Set xlSht = Sheets("Main")
  .Bookmarks("ProjectName1").Range.Text = xlSht.Range("B10").Value
  .Bookmarks("ProjectName2").Range.Text = xlSht.Range("B11").Value
  .Bookmarks("ProjectName3").Range.Text = xlSht.Range("B12").Value
  .Bookmarks("ProjectName4").Range.Text = xlSht.Range("B13").Value
  .Bookmarks("ProjectName5").Range.Text = xlSht.Range("B14").Value

  For Each cell In xlRng
    objRng.InsertAfter vbCr & cell.Offset(0, -1).Text
     Select Case LCase(cell.Value)
        Case "title"
          objRng.Paragraphs.Last.Style = .Styles("Heading 1")
        Case "main"
          objRng.Paragraphs.Last.Style = .Styles("Heading 2")
        Case "sub"
          objRng.Paragraphs.Last.Style = .Styles("Heading 3")
        Case "sub-sub"
          objRng.Paragraphs.Last.Style = .Styles("Heading 4")
        Case "par"
          objRng.Paragraphs.Last.Style = .Styles("Normal")
    End Select
  Next cell
  Set xlSht = Sheets("Main")
  .SaveAs2 ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & _
    xlSht.Range("B2").Value & ", " & _
    xlSht.Range("B3").Value & "_" & _
    xlSht.Range("B4").Value & "_" & _
    xlSht.Range("B5").Value & ".docx"
  objUndo.EndCustomRecord
  .Undo
  .Application.Quit False '<---- Please close Word application
End With
Set objWord = Nothing '<---- Please free up objWord
End Sub
```

Comment: Yet another cross-post: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/general-excel-discussion-other-questions/1085420-word-vba-give-number-heading-post5216778.html#post5216778 It is getting rather tiresome finding the same question in multiple forums with no cross-referencing... For cross-posting etiquette, kindly read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When automating another Office application memory can get "tied up" for various reasons. One important factor is managing *objects* the code has been using. At some point, these need to be "released" in order to free up memory. If they aren't properly disposed of, they can keep the application open (even if it's not visible) and cause problems.

One possible problem *could be* the multiple instantiation of `xlSheet`. Since it's always being assigned the same worksheet, this only needs to be done once. If you want to re-use an object (for a different object) and the code has problems, first set the object to `Nothing` before assigning a different object to it. (This is usually not necessary but sometimes it helps.)

The code in the question is running in Excel and uses a number of Word objects. These Word objects can become a problem (the Excel objects will "go out of scope" when the procedure ends). Therefore, it's good coding practice to set the object so `Nothing` as soon as they are no longer needed.

Sample code from the question to illustrate:

```
  With objWord  'a Word document
     objUndo.EndCustomRecord
    .Undo
    Set objUndo = Nothing '<---- Release Word objects in Excel code
    Set objRng = Nothing
    .Application.Quit False '<---- Please close Word application
  End With
  Set objWord = Nothing '<---- Please free up objWord
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't know if it should be a new question. However it is related to this question. I have set two of these codes in a row and call from the same macro (by call). First code runs OK but on second one I am getting Error that points to seconds code `sh.OLEFormat.Activate`. I tried to set everything to `= Nothing`. But still can't run two same functions in a row for different sheets and different templates.

Comment: @user7202022 Make it a new question, with a [mcve]. At some point, it's necessary to have a *reproducible* example we can set up quickly and easily. Only so much can be done using guess work and duct tape...