# Copy Excel range to embedded Word document skipping "" (empty cells)

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

(This question is a follow-up on [how to work with a document embedded in an Excel workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54445491/excel-vba-copy-range-all-cells-from-the-left-to-embedded-word-document/) in the Word application interface (instead of in-place). The reason this is necessary is to be able to save the result as an independent document.)

The problem is that I have dynamic content in Excel. In cells of Column E I have actually formula, for example E55 `=IF(B55="";"";"normal")` E55 is also `=IF('Technical!B55'="";"";'Technical!B55')`. My current code does not understand that for example cell B57 is empty and thinks it should be printed to MS Word. It does not insert any content to MS Word but inserts for example bullets that are predefined for style in MS Word. How to stop that? I can make for example `=IF(B55="";"empty";"normal")` so unnecessary rows will be marked with word "empty" if it helps anyhow.

```
   A    B                   C                   D                  E
49    Paragraph with number 1                                    main
48    Ok text is text and it is good to have here.. a lot of     normal
50    Legal             John Smith                               table
51                      Telephone         +4854132155            table 
52                      Email             john.smith@mail.com    table
53    Paragraph with number 2                                    main
54    Text again a lot of text again comes here                  normal
55    Text again a lot of text again comes here                  normal
56    Text again a lot of text again comes here                  normal
57    =IF('Technical!B57'="";"";'Technical!B57')                 =IF(B57="";"";"normal")            
58    =IF('Technical!B58'="";"";'Technical!B58')                 =IF(B58="";"";"normal")
```

My current code:

```
With objWord
  Set wdRng = .Range.Characters.Last
  Set wdUndo = .Application.UndoRecord
  wdUndo.StartCustomRecord ("Doc Data")
  Set xlSht = Sheets("Other Data")
  'Here comes Header
  .Bookmarks("Date").Range.Text = xlSht.Range("AT2").Value
  .Bookmarks("DocumentName").Range.Text = xlSht.Range("AX13").Value
Set xlSht = Nothing

Set xlSht = Sheets("Pricelist")
  For Each cell In xlRng
    wdRng.InsertAfter vbCr & cell.Offset(0, -4).Text
     Select Case LCase(cell.Value)
        Case "title"
          wdRng.Paragraphs.Last.Style = .Styles("Heading 1")
        Case "main"
          wdRng.Paragraphs.Last.Style = .Styles("Heading 2")
        Case "sub"
          wdRng.Paragraphs.Last.Style = .Styles("Heading 3")
        Case "sub-sub"
          wdRng.Paragraphs.Last.Style = .Styles("Heading 4")
        Case "normal"
          wdRng.Paragraphs.Last.Style = .Styles("Normal")
        Case "contact"
          wdRng.Paragraphs.Last.Style = .Styles("Contact")
          Case "attachment"
          wdRng.Paragraphs.Last.Style = .Styles("Attachment")
          Case "technical"
          wdRng.Paragraphs.Last.Style = .Styles("Technical")
          Case "topic"
          wdRng.Paragraphs.Last.Style = .Styles("Topic")
          Case "signature"

           Sheets("Signatures").Range("M7:N7").Copy

  With wdRng

    .Paragraphs.Last.Range.PasteSpecial (wdPasteBitmap)

  End With

          Case "pagebreak"
     With wdRng
     .Paragraphs.Last.Range.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
     End With
          Case "table"

          xlSht.Range(cell.Offset(0, -4), cell.Offset(0, -1)).Copy

  With wdRng

    .Paragraphs.Last.Range.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatPlainText)

  End With

    End Select
  Next cell
  .SaveAs2 ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & _
Sheets("Other Data").Range("AN2").Value & ", " & _
Sheets("Other Data").Range("AN7").Value & "_" & _
Sheets("Other Data").Range("AN8").Value & "_" & _
Sheets("Other Data").Range("AX3").Value & ".docx"

  wdUndo.EndCustomRecord
  Set wdUndo = Nothing
  .Undo
  .Application.Quit False
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes it is good to have a cup of tea and think about something else. I have came up with an idea of using `=IF(B55="";"empty";"normal")` so I will get word "empty" in unnecessary cells. Then I created new Case with name "empty" and used following code:

```
         Case "empty"

  With wdRng

    .Paragraphs.Last.Range.Delete

  End With
```

I don't know if this is the best solution. At least it works.

Comment: Feel free to mark your answer as correct. In that way you help others facing the same problem.