# "Nullify" Word style before pasting an Excel table in the document

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a code ([Full code can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54464568/excel-vba-copy-range-to-embedded-word-document-skip-empty-cells/54465519#54465519)) for inserting data from Excel to embedded Word document. It reads cell commands (cases) and inputting data to Word based on them (see screenshot above "main", "attachment", "table2"). The problem is that if there is no style defined for some Case it takes previous style.

I have came across the problem while copying Excel range and inserting it to my document. Code takes style "attachment" parameters and inserting table with predefined style "Attachment" to Word. How to null previous style parameters before inserting range to Ms Word?

Here is my code for inserting table:

```
                  Set xlSht = Sheets("Service")
               Case "table2"
        xlSht.Range("B11:I20").Copy
     With wdRng
  .Paragraphs.Last.Range.PasteExcelTable False, False, False
  .Tables(.Tables.Count).AutoFitBehavior wdAutoFitWindow
End With
```

VBA code result:
[image]

Manually copied:
[image]

In Excel:
[image]

Comment: @CindyMeister yes. It does not simply copy paste, but paste with previous row style. So in this case (according to my screenshot) it first inputs "Topic One" with predefined style for Case "main". Then if I do not input "attachment" on the next row Ms Word thinks it should continue with style for "main". So it inputs data according to Case "main" and for "main" I have "Heading 1". If I input "attachment" then it switches to "Attachment" predefined style in Ms Word. I would like it to get rid of style parameters of previous Case.

Comment: Side note: I've edited the titles of a few questions to make them more "recognizable" by others. Since Stack Overflow has tags it's not necessary to use "Excel" or "Excel VBA" in a title - people see the tags and know what it targets :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a case where you want to "nullify" all style information do that *before* pasting the table. The "null" style in Word is the Normal style; this style is also "safest" when inserting tables*.

The following code snippet, based on the code in the question, first applies the style, then pastes the table.

```
Dim rngPara as Word.Range
Set rngPara = .Paragraphs.Last.Range
rngPara.Style = wdStyleNormal
rngPara.PasteExcelTable False, False, False
```

*Besides paragraph and character formatting Word also has table styles. These are a special kind of style that determines table formatting (as opposed to paragraph or character formatting)). These are only applied correctly when a table is created in an empty paragraph formatted with the Normal style.

Comment: I have also messed up with Normal style... as I have changed it's parameters. Should have created a new one and leave Normal as it is. I have to edit my Word template as well. Thank you again a million!

Comment: @user7202022 Yes, it's always a good idea to create a new style for the "body" unless you want the changed style specifications to filter through ("inherit") for other styles. Once you have enough experience, when you plan out a project like this one, that kind of thing (styles) will be part of the preparation before any code is written :-) For now, though, chalk it up to part of the learning curve - which is quite steep, here!