# Work with embedded Word document from Excel (late binding)

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am wondering is there a possibility to remove reference to Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library and edit code so that it would work in both Office 2013 and Office 2016?

This code is for opening embedded Word document, writing data into it and saving it to user desktop. After that it quitting Word application.

```
Sub opentemplateWord()
    Dim sh As Shape
    Dim objWord As Object, objNewDoc As Object ''Word.Document
    Dim objOL As OLEObject
    Dim wSystem As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim wdRng As Object 'Word.Range
    Dim xlRng As Excel.Range
    Dim tempFolderPath As String
    Dim filePath As String
    Dim fileTitle As String

    Set wSystem = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Templates")
        ''The shape holding the object from 'Create from file'
        ''Object 2 is the name of the shape
    Set sh = wSystem.Shapes("LetterTemplate")
         ''The OLE Object contained
    Set objOL = sh.OLEFormat.Object
         'Instead of activating in-place, open in Word
    objOL.Verb xlOpen
    Set objWord = objOL.Object 'The Word document

    Dim objUndo As Object 'Word.UndoRecord
        'Be able to undo all editing performed by the macro in one step
    Set objUndo = objWord.Application.UndoRecord
    objUndo.StartCustomRecord "Edit In Word"

    With objWord
        'Cover page
    .Bookmarks("CoverPage").Range.Text = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Other Data").Range("AK4").Value

    Set xlRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Letter").Range("G3", ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Offer Letter").Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

    Set wdRng = .Range.Characters.Last

    For Each cell In xlRng
        wdRng.InsertAfter vbCr & cell.Offset(0, -5).Text
        Select Case LCase(cell.Value)

    Case "signature"
       Worksheets("Contact database").Shapes("Signature").Copy
        With wdRng
        .Paragraphs.Last.Range.Paste (wdPasteDefault)
        End With

    If ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents.Count = 1 Then _
  ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents(1).Update

        objWord.SaveAs2 Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\" & _
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Other Data").Range("AU2").Value & ".docx"

        objUndo.EndCustomRecord
        Set objUndo = Nothing
        objWord.Undo
        .Application.Quit False

    End With
    Set objWord = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: You seem to be aware of the concept of late binding, so what's the actual problem?  FYI with no Word reference you cannot use constants such as `wdPasteDefault` without either defining them in your code or substituting their numeric values.  If you use `Option Explicit` it will warn you about that type of problem.

Comment: Yes, I am already familiar with this one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdpastedatatype I am just wondering how the beginning of the code should be with all the variables set correct and `Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")`

Comment: It's just as shown in the question your code seems partially sourced from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54419143/edit-word-document-embedded-in-a-workbook-and-save-as-copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the reference on an Office 2013 system, it will work with Office 2016 & later without the need to change anything.